# Explore ODBC Database From Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, odbc, driver

I've been Googling this for a while now without much luck, but I suspect if it is possible it should be quite straight forward...

I have an ODBC connection set up within Windows to Sage 50 Accounts, with the DSN of SageLine50v22.  I can browse through the Sage database using standalone ODBC programs, but I was wondering if it's possible to connect to it from Netbeans (v8.1) directly, so that I can browse through the database from within the IDE, in the same way I could with a MySQL or SQLLite connection?  Please note - I am not trying to connect my actual code to the database - I only want to be able to browse it (I think the Sage ODBC connector is one way only anyway).

I was trying to use the Oracle/Oracle Thin drivers, since the driver is called ODBC7.jar, but I'm beginning to suspect I may be barking up the wrong tree, since all the Google results seem to indicate this is for connecting to ODBC programmatically using Java.  Can any one clear this up for me?

Comment: Why use ODBC? Nowadays every DBMS has a real JDBC driver (and `ojdbc7.jar` **is** a JDBC driver for Oracle, not an ODBC driver). java 8 does not support ODBC any more, only JDBC.

Comment: Because Sage comes with an ODBC connector - could you tell me how to connect to it directly instead?  I have tried this before many times and always been unsuccessful, but with the ODBC it has always been straightforward.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what that Sage thing is. Check if they have a **JDBC** driver.

Comment: I have just checked and the UK version of Sage 50 Accounts uses a proprietary database - so I guess ODBC is the only way after all?

Comment: OK I will look for JDBC driver, thanks.

Comment: I have found a JDBC driver but you have to pay for it.  Since I can already connect for free via ODBC I would still prefer to do it this way if it is possible.